# Android ViewPager inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a RecyclerView which has ViewPagers as its rows.
I set the ViewPager's adapter inside the onBind() method of RecyclerView Adapter.
But when I run the app, It looks like the number of pages inside each ViewPager gets incorrect after scrolling the RecyclerView.

Here is the body of my onBind() method

```
val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(itemList[position])
myViewPager.adapter = adapter
```

Here is MyViewPagerAdapter class

```
class MyViewPagerAdapter(val pages:List<Page>) : PagerAdapter() {

override fun isViewFromObject(view: View, `object`: Any): Boolean {
    return `object` == view
}

override fun getCount() = pages.size

override fun instantiateItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int): Any {
    val v: View = LayoutInflater.from(container.context).inflate(R.layout.view_pager_row, container, false)
    container.addView(v, position)
    // do some bindings
    return v
}

override fun destroyItem(container: ViewGroup, position: Int, `object`: Any) {
    try {
        container.removeView(`object` as View)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }
}
```

PS:

I finally used a RecyclerView with horizontal LinearLayoutManager and SnapHelper to simulate a ViewPager and the problem is resolved.

Comment: Please add more code.

Comment: Please share your implementation of doing this, that we all can be able to help you precisely.